# how can i make the 3 divs move away farther from each other

Tags: html, css

im trying to make the divs that have the h1 elements as shown in the picture provided below to move away from each other and not be this close to each other but i cant seem to do so i dont know if adding a width to each does anything. i tried adding margin and padding aswell but it moves the whole page instead of each div indivdually

here is the main section in the html file

```
<main>
    <div class="who">
        <h1>Who We Are</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="what">
        <h1>What We Do</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="where">
        <h1>Where We Work</h1>
    </div>
    
</main>
```

and here is the css file

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    color: #222;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

header{
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul li a{
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
}

li a::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:4px;
    width:0;
    background: #FCAE1E;
}

li a:hover::after{
width:100%;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    height:calc(100vh - 100px);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


.who{
    width: 30%;
}
.what{
    width: 30%;
}
.where{
    width: 30%;
}
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnnV0.png)

Comment: Give `main` a CSS `gap` value or adjust the `justify-content` to `space-around` or `space-between`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try justify-content: space-between

[https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/#:~:text=The%20justify%2Dcontent%20property%20is,have%20reached%20their%20maximum%20size](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/#:%7E:text=The%20justify%2Dcontent%20property%20is,have%20reached%20their%20maximum%20size)

Follow the link above for more info

Comment: should i add it to the main or to each div?

Comment: You should add it to main div

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your CSS file:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
}
```